# Python selenium - Find element in elements loop

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to ask for help. I try on website https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/100 scrape overall rating under main title of all articles but when I do it, it will print:

```
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
4,8
```

But there are more ratings not just 4,8. So I want to find element in elements loop. I would like to do it in this type of loop if it's possible.
Here is my code:

```
art = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[@class='index__contentBlock__7vKo-']")
    for i in art:
        pr = i.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='index__score__16yy9']").text
        print(pr)
```

Comment: For documentation purposes, accept the answer that helped you the most or provide feedback as to what do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You've already gathered all the elements in art.

All you have to do is:

```
art = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[@class='index__contentBlock__7vKo-']")
for i in art:
    print(i.text)
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: but I want to print just   i.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='index__score__16yy9']").text not whole text

Answer (score 0):

This should print all articles with index_score.

```
art = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[@class='index__contentBlock__7vKo-']//span[@class='index__score__16yy9']")

for i in art:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the ratings e.g. *2,0* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/100')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='index__ratingBlock'] span[class^='index__score__']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/100')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'index__ratingBlock')]//span[starts-with(@class, 'index__score__')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['2,0', '4,5', '3,8', '4,8', '2,8', '4,7', '3,2', '4,0', '4,9', '4,2']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)